# WPF Binding to a static resource not working

Tags: c#, wpf

**Edit:** the question has been changed to reduce the issue to a complete MWE.

I have a static resource in a resource dictionary Icons.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MWE">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="IconGeometry">
        <Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
            <Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
                <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <DrawingBrush>
                            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                <DrawingGroup>
                                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M16,5.5C16,8.538 13.538,11 10.5,11 10.225,11 9.957,10.973 9.693,10.934 9.667,10.93 9.641,10.927 9.615,10.922 9.337,10.877 9.066,10.816 8.804,10.731L4.268,15.268C3.795,15.74 3.167,16 2.5,16 1.833,16 1.205,15.74 0.731999999999999,15.268 -0.242000000000001,14.293 -0.242000000000001,12.707 0.731999999999999,11.732L5.269,7.196C5.184,6.934 5.123,6.662 5.078,6.384 5.073,6.359 5.07,6.333 5.066,6.307 5.027,6.043 5,5.775 5,5.5 5,2.462 7.462,0 10.5,0 13.538,0 16,2.462 16,5.5" />
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF424242" Geometry="F1M15,5.5C15,7.985 12.985,10 10.5,10 9.807,10 9.158,9.83 8.571,9.55L3.561,14.561C3.268,14.854 2.884,15 2.5,15 2.116,15 1.732,14.854 1.439,14.561 0.853999999999999,13.975 0.853999999999999,13.025 1.439,12.439L6.45,7.429C6.17,6.842 6,6.193 6,5.5 6,3.015 8.015,1 10.5,1 11.193,1 11.842,1.17 12.429,1.45L9.636,4.243 11.757,6.364 14.55,3.571C14.83,4.158,15,4.807,15,5.5" />
                                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                </DrawingGroup>
                            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        </DrawingBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </Viewbox>
        </Viewbox>
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

This is the corresponding App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="MWE.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MWE"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Icons.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Here is my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MWE.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MWE"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding Path=TestIcon, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And lastly the MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace MWE
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public DataTemplate _TestIcon { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate TestIcon
        { 
            get
            {
                return _TestIcon;
            }
            set
            {
                _TestIcon = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TestIcon");
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TestIcon = Application.Current.TryFindResource("IconGeometry") as DataTemplate;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handlers = PropertyChanged;
            handlers(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Why isn't `TestIcon` displaying? If I instead use `<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource IconGeometry}"/>` the icon displays, so I know that the static resource has been correctly defined and merged into the application resource dictionary.

Comment: You need to show the code of your dataTemplate.. it seems to some binding inside it not correct. Also want admit to strange use type DataTemplate for property Icon.

Comment: Hi Anton, I'm still new to WPF so I wasn't too sure what to use for the icon. Is there a better alternative then to use a `DataTemplate`? Bearing in mind my icon is a `ViewBox` with vector drawings in it.

Comment: I have been doing some searching online and I think I might need a converter. Could someone please give me an example of how to implement this?

Comment: I'd try to find where the "chain" breaks down. You know that `TryFindResource` is working, so you can start from the next "link". Is `GeometryPageViewModel.Icon` being called at all (test it with a breakpoint)? If so, is it returning the expected value? If so, is `MainTreeItem.Icon` being called (again, test with breakpoint)? Etc.

Comment: @KeithStein That was a good suggestion. I checked with a breakpoint and the getter for `GeometryPageViewModel.Icon` is never called. What is strange though is that the getter for `GeometryPageViewModel.TreeName` is called. And the code for the two are pretty much identical.

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere. `MainTreeItem.Icon` is what's supposed to be calling it, right? Is that getter ever being called? If so, how is that if statement evaluating?

Comment: @KeithStein have reduced the question to a complete MWE. The getter for `TestIcon` is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you don't set `MainWindow.DataContext` anywhere, but as I found out, it doesn't work even when you do. The problem, as I discovered, is that you shouldn't be using `ContentPresenter` for something like this. Instead, use `ContentControl`.

I added the ever-helpful `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to the binding from your example, and noticed an interesting line in the output:

> Found data context element: ContentPresenter

Even after I set `MainWindow.DataContext`, the `ContentPresenter` was still using itself as the `DataContext`, which is why the binding wasn't working properly, but the `StaticResource` was. Further research lead me to [this article](https://alexfeinberg.wordpress.com/2014/10/11/wpf-the-real-difference-between-contentcontrol-and-contentpresenter/) and this quote:

> ContentPresenter’s DataContext is automatically set to the value of its Content property, while ContentControl’s DataContext is not.

The article goes into a bit more detail on the difference between the two elements.

So there you go. Make sure the `DataContext` is set correctly, then swap out the `ContentPresenter`s for `ContentControl`s.

Comment: Your solution worked, thank you very much for your help. The DataContext difference between `ContentPresenter` and `ContentControl` was a very subtle difference that I did not pick up on.